# Call api on alternate port

Tags: python, api

Does anyone know of a way to call a standard api on port 80 from an application via a different port?
For example, I am working on a project that only has access to port 995, and I would like to make api calls on a web api on port 80 thru port 995.

Does something like an online proxy port forwarder exist?

Any help greatly appreciated!!

Comment: When you specify the API URL, add `:portnumber` after the hostname, e.g. `https://www.google.com:995`

Comment: ```project that only has access to port 995```: do you mean that any outgoing connection to port other than 995 will be rejected (dropped) by some kind of firewall, OR your application (API client) will/can only listen port 995?

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply, guys! To clarify, any outgoing connection other than port 995 will be blocked, this is due to an external firewall. Is there any way to call a standard API on port 80 thru port 995? Is it possible via some online middleware maybe?